# Update column with the max of a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-update

In SQL Server, let's consider this table:

| Id | PartNumber | Timestamp | Reintegration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 2020-01-01 | NULL |
| 2 | 1111 | 2020-01-02 | NULL |
| 3 | 2222 | 2021-02-01 | NULL |
| 4 | 2222 | 2021-02-02 | NULL |

I want to update the `Reintegration` column with the `MAX` value of a `Group By PartNumber`.

Here is the expected result :

| Id | PartNumber | Timestamp | Reintegration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1111 | 2020-01-01 | NULL |
| 2 | 1111 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-02 |
| 3 | 2222 | 2021-02-01 | NULL |
| 4 | 2222 | 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-02 |

I have tried a lot of thing with `GROUP BY`, `MAX`, `INNER JOIN`, without success.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window function `max() over()` seems like a nice fit here.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=bbf6471e4376f12091b8e9eaaab2e39e)**

```
with cte as (
Select *
      ,MaxDate = max([TimeStamp]) over (partition by PartNumber) 
 from YourTable
)
Update cte set [Reintegration] = MaxDate
 Where [TimeStamp] = MaxDate
```

**The Updated Table**

```
Id  PartNumber  Timestamp     Reintegration
1   1111        2020-01-01    NULL
2   1111        2020-01-02    2020-01-02
3   2222        2021-02-01    NULL
4   2222        2021-02-02    2021-02-02
```